# Inclusion of Ideals: $(x,y)^2 = (x^2, xy, y^2) \subsetneq (x^2, y) \subsetneq (x,y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I am reading Algebra written by Dummit and Foote. Let $F$ be a field and $(x,y)$ be an ideal of $F[x,y].$
On page 682 Examples (3) the book says that $$(x,y)^2 = (x^2, xy, y^2) \subsetneq (x^2, y) \subsetneq (x,y).$$

Is $(x,y)^2\subsetneq (x^2,y)$ because $y\not\in (x,y)^2$? But how can we express $xy$ by elements of $(x^2,y)?$

Is $(x^2,y)\subsetneq (x,y)$ because $x\not\in (x^2,y)$?

Comment: $xy$ is in $(x^2,y)$ because $y\in (x^2,y)$, and since the latter is an ideal, $y\in (x^2,y)$ implies $xy\in (x^2,y)$. And yes.

Comment: **Hint** $\ f(x,y) \in (g(x,y),y)\iff g(x,0)\mid f(x,0),\, $ by evaluating at $\,y=0\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

$y\notin (x,y)^{2}$: suppose $y\in (x,y)^{2}$. Then $y=f(x,y)x^{2}+g(x,y)xy+h(x,y)y^{2}$ for some $f,g,h\in F[x,y]$. So $y=h(0,y)y^{2}$, and $1=h(0,y)y$. $h(0,y)\neq 0$. The degree of LHS is $0$, but the degree of RHS is $\geq 1$, contradiction.

$xy\in (x^{2},y)$: because $xy=0\cdot x^{2}+x\cdot y$.

$x\notin (x^{2},y)$: suppose $x\in (x^{2},y)$. Then $x=f(x,y)x^{2}+g(x,y)y$ for some $f,g\in F[x,y]$. So $x=f(x,0)x^{2}$, and $1=f(x,0)x$. Similarly as before, this is a contradiction.

Comment: More simply & generally see my comment on the answer.

Comment: That works for the last statement. What about the first one?

Comment: First is same as last with $x,y$ swapped, using $\,(x,y)^2\subset (x,y^2)\ \ $